# What do you call that noise one might make in response to something they are unimpressed or appalled by?

Tags: word-choice

This is probably a stupid question. You know, that exhalation of air? Close to a tutting sound. It's like a non verbal response when someone is disgusted or appalled by something another person says/does.

Comment: How about *sigh*?

Comment: Pbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbt

Comment: Let's see what you want your sentence to look like.

Comment: Each of "Unimpressed," "appalled" and "disgusted," has its own distinct sound.

Answer (score 2):

A good, old fashioned *snort* comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider [***harrumphed***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20harrumphed)

> - clear the throat noisily.
> - grumpily express dissatisfaction or disapproval

Closer to *tutting* is [***tisking***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=to%20tsk&oq=to%20tsk) (or ***tsk***).

> exclamation to express disapproval or annoyance

Answer (score 1):

Unimpressed: *[meh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/meh)*

Disgusted: *[ugh](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ugh)*

Appalled: *[tsk tsk](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tsk_tsk)*

Comment: Acknowledged, "tisking (or tsk)" has already been mentioned by @PCARR

Answer (score -1):

Try these:

- Snort: dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snort
- Grunt: dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grunt
- Groan: dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/groan
- Sigh:  dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sigh

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: All the above-mentioned words are universally accepted sounds made in response to something unimpressive, distressing or appalling.

Snort: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snort
Grunt: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grunt
Groan: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/groan
Sigh: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sigh

Comment: Yeah, please edit your answer to explain that.